# Solve 429 Too Many Requests issue while load testing using Jmeter

Tags: apache, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm trying to hit the server with multiple requests for load testing. I have setup JMeter thread with 100 concurrent users per seconds. Each request read data from CSV (different tokens to identify users). But after few request I'm getting error:

```
429 Too Many Requests
```

How we can solve this? Any settings in Jmeter?

Or Do I need to change Apache settings?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

As per [HTTP Status 429 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

> The **HTTP 429 Too Many Requests** response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
>
> A [Retry-After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

Most probably your JMeter test configuration is not correct, the reasons could be in:

- You don't use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) so all the requests fall under the same session and application reacts correspondingly
- Your application limits rate of requests from a single IP. Consider going for [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) or [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) or both
- You're using the same credentials for all virtual users, make sure that each JMeter virtual user has its own credentials and operates its own data. You can use i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a DDOS protection in the application you’re testing so your options are to ask the infrastructure team or developers to disable it.

As per [reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429):

```
The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.
```

There is nothing you can do ok jmeter side.